# Editing previous questions to direct to new post

Tags: discussion, edits, rollbacks

While browsing recent questions I came across [this new post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11570099/dynamic-pivot-with-nulls-using-count-and-cte-when-columns-are-unknown) in which the user is referencing older questions they asked that have already been answered and accepted.

When you go to the old questions ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11404062/sql-server-advanced-report-of-multiple-rows-into-one), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11459355/sql-server-2005-fill-pivot-table-with-0s) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11465666/sql-server-2005-percentage-in-parenthesis-in-pivot-table)) the user has edited all of these older posts to reference the new question(s).

It seems like noise to have the older posts edited to reference the new post.  Should the older questions be rolled back to the original versions?  Should the user be told to not do this?  What is the proper way of handling this?

Comment: I am the OP. Thanks for pointing this out. My thought process was that rather than noise, I would be giving people who had helped me before the "first shot" at getting the new accepted answer. I assumed that updating the old question to link to the new one would specifically alert them to my follow up, where linking to the old question from the new one might not get their attention at all. Am I wrong?

Comment: Linking the to new question from the old one doesn't notify anyone of the new question. You would have to add a comment to the accepted answer to get their attention.

Comment: So would it make sense to add a link in the comment of the accepted answer pointing to the new question? Or would this also be noise-y?

Comment: I am not sure what the protocol would be, if it was me I would _not_ leave it on the other accepted answers that would be noisy.  If you are unsure you can always ask a question here on meta about what do to in those cases.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I removed the links the OP added on the old questions.

The new question links to the old ones, so if you look in the right sidebar you will see that, in the old questions, there is *already a referral link to the new question.* So the forward links added to the bodies of the old questions are redundant.

Comment: cool, thanks.  should the user be told that it is unnecessary to do the updating with the links on the old posts?  I just wasn't sure the proper etiquette.

Comment: I already left the OP a link to this post.