# Add a link in comment of accepted answer notify follow up?

Tags: discussion, questions, comments

In this [post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/140486/editing-previous-questions-to-direct-to-new-post) I was softly corrected for adding a link to a follow-up question to the question body of an old answered question.

If jimmy123 has been helpful in answering my first question, should I add a link in the comments of his accepted answer that will alert him of my new question?

Since he was so helpful and is familiar with the context of my question, I want him to have the first crack at the points for my 2nd accepted answer. I want to be loyal. Without being noisy.

Please advise.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Personally I don't think you should solicit help from people explicitly. This is likely why there isn't a way to contact someone directly/privately. I have seen several scenarios where people get pestered by certain individuals to help them solve their new problem because they were helpful before. Let them come to you. IMHO.

Comment: I hear what you are saying because it could be bothersome. I think letting them come to me has merit but giving them an reputation advantage also seems like a good thing to do.

Comment: If they do come to you, you can still reward them by using that as part of your criteria for up-voting/accepting. Having been on the other side, I think trying to pressure them into coming to you is going to have the opposite effect than what you expect. Users with high rep are not highly motivated by being told which questions to work on, even if it is that more likely they'll get 25 points out of it. Reputation is not currency and does not fill the gas tank or feed the kids.

Comment: If I post my question, it will possibly a duplicate of this one but I don't want to address the same person only redirect others that might have the same new question to resolve. How about linking then? And should one put it in the comments of the question rather then the answer?

Comment: @JohnSmith I still think your idea is flawed. No matter which way you try to flag down this user, it is more likely to be seen as pestering than anything else. Why don't you just post your question, if it's a good question you'll get good answers, if you tag it right this user should still find it, and stop worrying about which individual users answer your questions and help you solve your problems. If you want to trigger better answers, start a bounty. Not sure why you're convinced that this one user is the best assistance you'll get across all of StackOverflow. Even Skeet is wrong sometimes.

Comment: @AaronBertand, BTW who is Skeet?

Comment: @John I thought your initial comment here had some relevance to the question on this page. I meant "flag down" as in "get their attention." If you have a question to ask of meta, please ask on meta, not as a comment to some unrelated answer. Also do you have any idea how many users are on meta? Do you also understand that [down-voting on meta is different](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#vote-differences) than on the main site?

Comment: Okay a misunderstanding. We're cool. Site is nagging: Would you like to automatically move this discussion to chat? So, anyway thanks for the feedback.

Comment: @JohnSmith why did you ask your question here as a comment to this answer, if it has nothing to do with the content on this page?

Comment: this is why, just posted it. It will be closed as duplicate: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/142684/when-one-gets-an-answer-but-a-follow-up-question-arises-could-i-link-to-it-in-t

Comment: you +20, me -2. Ain't that cool ;). Yes I already knew about the right answer versus agree with difference. Where on no site it's personal or whatever. Am quitting comments here as my intention is by far pestering. My apologies for this misunderstanding.