# When one gets an answer but a follow up question arises, could I link to it in the comment?

Tags: asking-questions, support

One asks a question and gets a sound answer but from that arises a new question. When asking the last in comment would be good but what if that question can be generalized and has a quite different context while extending the first answer?

Would it be a good idea to work out the new question and put a link to there in the comment of the answer which raised the question?

Answer (score 5):

> Would it be a good idea to work out the new question and put a link to there in the comment of the answer which raised the question?

Absolutely - this is a very good thing to do, but if you do, make sure your comment includes the fact that the link is to a followup question and the gist of it.

Stack Overflow is about answering questions and if one person has a follow on question, others will surely have it as well, so giving them a link to follow makes the site better.

To address [Aaron's comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/142684/when-one-gets-an-answer-but-a-follow-up-question-arises-could-i-link-to-it-in-t/142685#comment404653_142685), since posting such a comment will alert the answer OP to the follow up, it can be construed as a request to "please look at this question too", which the OP is under no obligations to do.

To combat this issue, you should only post such a link if there already are good answers on it and make it clear in the link that it includes answers (so the OP will not feel awkward if they are unable to follow up).

Comment: how old can the old question be before your answer changes from "absolutely" to something else? Just wondering because this is somewhat related to [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/140599/add-a-link-in-comment-of-accepted-answer-notify-follow-up/).

Comment: @AaronBertrand - I don't think the age of the question matters. If there is a follow on to it, it should be posted, so others can follow. I agree that this shouldn't be a solicitation to the poster of the answer, but a service to other users (the assumption being that an answer _has_ been given to the follow up).

Comment: Thanks for addressing that, I think there are some grey (or gray) areas there...

Comment: @AaronBertrand - matters of intent... If the intent is to point other users to the follow up, great. If it is to get the OP to answer yet another question, whether they want to or not, not so great. If only we could determine intent from the text of the comment.